# nested for loops to list comprehension with differents "if" conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, nested-loops

I'm trying to convert this nested loop into a list comprehension but i'm not sure it's possible as there is different values possible for item in "tmp" list. Is it the best way to do this ? Thanks !

```
final = []
for a in range(-13, 1):
    for b in range(0,4):
        for c in range(6, 49):
            for d in range(48, 94):
                tmp = [0 for i in range(100)]
                for i in range(100):
                    if raw_x[i] >= b and raw_y[i] >= d:
                        tmp [i] = -1
                    if raw_x[i] <= a and raw_y[i] <= c:
                        tmp [i] = 1
                final.append(tmp)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in one expression although I'm not sure readability is improved:

```
final = [
    [
        +1 if x <= a and y <= c
        else -1 if x >= b and y >= d
        else 0
        for x, y in zip( raw_x, raw_y )
    ]
    for a in range(-13, 1)
    for b in range(0, 4)
    for c in range(6, 49)
    for d in range(48, 94)
]
```

Note that I've assumed you want to go through the *whole* of `raw_x` and `raw_y` rather than exactly 100 elements every time: the question implies 100-every-time but if the intention is really to go through the whole sequence, then it's better not to hard-code the 100 in there.  If I'm wrong about the intention, you can change that inner-comprehension `for` loop to `for i in range(100)` and use `raw_x[i]` and `raw_y[i]` in the conditional expression instead of `x` and `y`.

Comment: thanks, that's what i wanted to know, even if the readability is not that improved

Answer (score 3):

nested comprehensions are not very readable

a simple

```
[something for something in container if something > 9]
```

is awesome, but a nested one is often confusing

you can simply move the loops into a generator function - it will still be readable and allow for lazy iteration

```
def no_idea_what_this_represents():
    for a in range(-13, 1):
        for b in range(0,4):
            for c in range(6, 49):
                for d in range(48, 94):
                    tmp = [0 for i in range(100)]
                    for i in range(100):
                        if raw_x[i] >= b and raw_y[i] >= d:
                            tmp [i] = -1
                        if raw_x[i] <= a and raw_y[i] <= c:
                            tmp [i] = 1
                    yield tmp

final = [signs for signs in no_idea_what_this_represents()]
```

EDIT: just an opinionated addendum - this way the complicated nested loop can be named ( I named it `no_idea_what_this_represents` for obvious reasons ) but when a programmer sees

```
possible_views = [matrix for matrix in camera_matrices()]
```

he immediately knows what that means while something like

```
possible_views = [device.matrix 
                  for devices in itertools.chain(connected_devices(), buffered_devices()
                  for device in devices
                  if device.type=='camera']
```

makes the programmer read a lot of lines and it is not obvious what is going on

Comment: Although it doesn't answer the actual question (turns out OP literally did just want to learn about complex comprehension expressions) this challenge to the premise makes a *very* good point about readability.  -1 and +1.

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm has large time complexity. First see if this is *actually* what you require. Once you are sure you need a nested `for` loop with 4 nesting levels, you can define a function to use *within* your list comprehension.

In this case, notice built-in [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) can accept multiple iterable arguments. [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) allows you to define functions with pre-set arguments.

```
from functools import partial

def get_val(x, y, a, b, c, d):
    if x <= a and y <= c:
        return 1
    if x >= b and y >= d:
        return -1
    return 0

final = [list(map(partial(get_val, a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d), raw_x, raw_y)) \
         for a in range(-13, 1) \
         for b in range(0, 4) \
         for c in range(6, 49) \
         for d in range(48, 94)]
```

Comment: @tobias_k  `map` handles the unpacking of the lists `raw_x` and `raw_y` into elements `x` and `y`

Comment: @jez Ah, right, did not see that (and apparantly did not read the description).

Comment: Note that, strictly, the order of precedence of -1 and +1 should be swapped if you want to match the question.   In the question,  if `x <=a and y<=c` then the value +1 overwrites the previous value, even if it was previously set to -1

Comment: @jez, Thanks for pointing out. Yes, that is true, since OP is potentially overwriting values in each `if` statement (intentionally or not, it's not clear). Corrected now.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i didn't choose it as i wanted only a list comprehension without external function, but i've learned something ! thanks @jez i don't even realise it

Comment: @TmSmth in that case be aware that my answer replicates the question's +1 -over- -1 precedence as well